# Digital control: Exercise solution

Tags: frequency-response, transfer-function, control-systems, performance

Can you help me (show me how) to solve the following exercise?

For the process with transfer function $G(s)=e^{-2s}/(s+1)$ design a digital controller with sampling time $T_{s} = 1$ that meets the specifications:

1. $e_{∞}$ (steady state error) null whit a step as input;
2. dominant poles in closed loop with damping $ζ≥0,5$;
3. settling time $T_{a1}≤20sec $.

Comment: Did you mean $e^-2s$ or $e^{-2s}$ ??

Comment: @Peter K. - I mean the second one: exp(-2s).

Comment: This is trivial, but i figure this homework expired so long timeeeee...